# distribute reads across replicas in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to understand the behavior of reads in a mongodb replica set. In particular I have an environment with high rate of reads, low rate of writes, and relatively small data set (say less than 8GB). I have a 3 node replica set.

I read this document:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-preference/

In particular:

> > primary  Default mode. All operations read from the current replica set primary.
> >
> > primaryPreferred In most situations, operations read from the primary but if it is unavailable, operations read from secondary members.
> >
> > secondary    All operations read from the secondary members of the replica set.
> >
> > secondaryPreferred   In most situations, operations read from secondary members but if no secondary members are available, operations read from the primary.
> >
> > nearest  Operations read from the nearest member of the replica set, irrespective of the member’s type.

So my understanding is that reads by default go to the primary. There are read preferences that allow reading from secondary (`secondary`, and `secondaryPreferred`). In these cases stale data may be served.

It seems to me that it would be preferable to distribute the reads across both primary and secondary machines, so that I can make best use off all 3 machines. But I don't really see this as an option. The following statement in particular perplexes me:

> > If read operations account for a large percentage of your application’s traffic, distributing reads to secondary members can improve read throughput. However, in most cases sharding provides better support for larger scale operations, as clusters can distribute read and write operations across a group of machines.

However, in the case of a relatively small data set, sharding simply doesn't make sense. Can someone shed some light on the right configuration?

Comment: why do you want to distribute reads to secondaries? it sounds like the primary will probably be able to serve your needs just fine.

Comment: what makes you think that? Can it handle 1K queries per second (with low latency, obviously)? What about 10K queries per second? Whatever my traffic load is, at some point one machine can't handle it, and then I'm going to want to distribute the traffic across machines.

Comment: Sure, I've tested systems that can handle 30K reads/second.  The way you scale or distribute is not via secondaries, it's via sharding.

Comment: But that's just the essence of my question. If I don't have a data size that really warrants sharding (and even 20GB these days can easily be in RAM on one box), why would I introduce that complexity? Is there not some reasonable way to scale traffic? After all, I have 3 machines, and only one of them is serving any traffic at all. It sure would be nice if I could actually _use_ those other two machines for something other than insurance.

Comment: do you want high availability?  that's what replica sets are for, primarily.  And if you're only doing reads, the only thing that would be limiting your throughput would be if you run out of connections or network bandwidth (and the driver should be connection pooling for you so that shouldn't be a limitation).

Comment: Hello @Kevin, I also want to distribute reads across my primary and secondary. Could you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

I had asked this question to in a forum of MongoDB, this was their answer,

TL;DR: Use nearest.

Indeed, sharding your cluster would definitely solve the problem as it would force you to split your data set into pieces (shards) and your reads and writes operations would be distributed evenly by the mongos servers - granted that you chose a good shard key.
But, as you found out, it doesn’t really makes sense for a relatively little data set and it would be more costly.

Our documentation doesn’t really reveal all the magic behind the “nearest” option, but there is actually a round-robin algorithm implemented behind it.
In our specifications, you can read more about it - especially about the options that you can set to tune the round-robin algorithm.

https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/server-selection/server-selection.rst#nearest
https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/driver-read-preferences.rst#nearest

```
To distribute reads across all members evenly regardless of RTT, users should use mode ‘nearest’ without tag_sets or maxStalenessSeconds and set localThresholdMS very high so that all servers fall within the latency window.
```

Here is more documentation about the [ping times](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/driver-read-preferences.rst#ping-times).

Especially this part:

```
Once the driver or mongos has found a list of candidate members based on mode and tag sets, determine the “nearest” member as the one with the quickest response to a periodic ping command. (The driver already knows ping times to all members, see “assumptions” above.) Choose a member randomly from those at most 15ms “farther” than the nearest member. The 15ms cutoff is overridable with “secondaryAcceptableLatencyMS”.
```

Also, the more RAM you have, the less documents will need to be retrieved from disk. If your working set 1 is large, you should considered adding some RAM to reduce the IOPS and overall latency.

Adding to what has mentioned above, the terminology is inconsistent in places but in https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/server-selection-next-generation-mongodb-drivers it clarifies that

```
The ‘localThresholdMS’ variable used to be called secondaryAcceptableLatencyMS, but was renamed for more consistency with mongos (which already had localThreshold as a configuration option) and because it no longer applies only to secondaries.
```

The `localThresholdMS` is a connection string used as part of uri option, docs can be found at https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.1/apidocs/mongodb-driver-core/com/mongodb/ConnectionString.html

Answer (score 0):

I was able to partially fix the issue, using tags reference https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-replica-set-tag-sets/

```
conf = rs.conf()
conf.members[1].tags = { "tagType": "dummyValue"}
rs.reconfig(conf)
```

A custom tag was set on each of the secondary machines, and different mongo templates (I am using Spring Mongo) were defined using the tag sets (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference/#tag-sets)

```
<bean id="tag" class="com.mongodb.Tag">
    <constructor-arg value="tagType" />
    <constructor-arg value="dummyValue" />
```

```
<bean id="tagSet" class="com.mongodb.TagSet">
    <constructor-arg ref="tag" />
</bean>

<bean id="readPref" class="com.mongodb.ReadPreference" 
        factory-method="secondaryPreferred" >
        <constructor-arg ref="tagSet" />
</bean>

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoFactory" />
        <property name="readPreference" ref="readPref" />
        <property name="writeConcern" value="JOURNALED" />
    </bean>
```

The calls were manually distributed using the different mongo templates and hence a partial solution to distributing the loads on the secondary mongo servers.

Comment: This does not solve the problem, the reads still go to only secondary, OP wanted the reads to be distributed across primary and secondaries of replica sets